# Transform an image loaded from a file to a Picture in XRender

Tags: render, x11, xlib

Let's say I have some kind of image in memory; this image is 4-channel RGBA. I would like to draw this image onto a window using the XRender extension to preserve the alpha channel. I already know how to draw a 3-channel RGB image, where:

- First, you create an empty `XImage` with appropriately allocated memory.
- Then, you iterate over the image's pixels and use `XPutPixel` in order to set the pixels of the `XImage`. For the `pixel` value, you use the `OR`d values of the blue channel, the green channel shifted 8 bytes to the left, and the red channel shifted 16 bytes to the left. There may be a way to incorporate the alpha channel into this, but after Googling I cannot find it. In addition, `OR`ing the `pixel` by a value shifted 24 bytes to the left does not seem to do anything.
- Then, you upload this `XImage` to the server by creating an appropriately sized `Pixmap` and using `XPutImage` to copy the image onto it.
- Finally, you create a `Picture` based upon the `Pixmap` using `XRenderCreatePicture`, and then use the `XRenderComposite` function to copy that onto the window, or other drawable if you so desire.

However, I need to be able to do this with the alpha channel. Is there a way to create a `Pixmap` with an alpha channel, or is there some kind of thing you need to do with the `Picture` in order to copy it? I thought the solution would be to create an alpha mask, but in order to create an alpha mask in `Picture` form it seems like you would need a `Pixmap` with an alpha channel, which brings us back to the original problem. I've tried Googling this problem but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring the XImage use a depth of 32 and XRenderFindStandardFormat(dpy, PictStandardARGB32) as *visual. Then the pixmap that you transfer the image on should also have the depth of 32 and the picture that you create should also have this *visual XRenderFindStandardFormat(dpy, PictStandardARGB32).